# "The NeverEnding Story" Hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I did what is required to "earn" this hat... I changed more than two things on my Developer Story... and I still haven't gotten this hat... Is there a thing that I have to activate or register/login somewhere or anything like that, so that the hats will be available to me?

And **YES** **I did** read the rules, info, guide and some questions and answers but still nothing has happened. I also tried to get other hats and also none of them work or appear...

Am I missing something?

Comment: There should be a patient hat.

Comment: Patience you must have...

Comment: You don't do things to get a hat... you do the things you would normally do, and as a side-effect get hats. Otherwise you're just a slave, and your master is a computer.

Comment: @Tunaki: _"You take the blue pill—the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe. You take the red pill—you stay in Wonderland, and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes."_

Comment: @Tunaki why? I don't usually browse meta, but I came here when I saw _I Am Your Father_ hat. That hat brought me here, which is good for meta. I LOVE that hat and want it in my collection. That's fun and it's recommended.

Comment: Looks like you have 4 hats by now - including Never Ending Story. Congratulations! Hats have one thing in common with badges: they don't come immediately. Usually hats come in about 15 minutes, though it may vary per hat.

Comment: This is a legitimate question and I am up voting it.  Hats are fun.  I want the hat too and I am having the same problem.  This is a good question - don't down vote it.

Comment: I have to be quite honest.  Even though hats are silly and just for fun, I am really disappointed with the SO community here.  This is a good question and the answers so far are very unhelpful.  The 12 downvotes is disrespectful.

Comment: @Jess I totally agree with you... I am a new member, not even two months and in my posts and other posts that I have browsed I have seen that this community sucks... there is so little helpful people... This community gets triggered way to easly... and then downvote and insult in the first chance they get... the arogance and passive-agresivness in the answers and comments is truly saddening... yet they consider them self some respectfull and civilized communitiy...

Comment: @weinde as a whole SO is AWESOME.  This is only the second time I have seen this.  As a new member, welcome!  I really love SO and I hope this will not affect your opinion too much.  Hang in there.  SO is amazingly useful.

Comment: @weinde In my case, if you do not update the `Recommended Reading` section, you will not get the hat. I updated almost every item expect `Recommended Reading`, but got the hat after I edited this section.

Comment: Apparently patience actually is the answer. I made two changes to my developer story in the first two days of Winterbash and haven't touched it since then. I got the hat two weeks later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short Answer:

Edit the **Recommended reading** section at the very bottom.  (Thanks for confirming this, @Senjuti Mahapatra)

## Long Answer:

OK.  I had the same problem and waiting patiently did not help.  The text on the hat says I only need to update 2 items.

[image]

So I updated 2 items and waited an entire day.  No hat.

I finally got the hat; Here are some things that I did in my **Developer Story**.

1. When you edit the section at the top, make sure to hit **Save**.  I missed that the first time and lost my edits. [image]
2. I edited **every section**.  There is nothing to indicate if any fields are required or not.  They all seem to be optional.
3. There is a **Recommended reading** section at the bottom which I missed the first time.  I just didn't notice it.
4. I don't know if this matters or not, but I made my developer story **public**.
   [image]

Comment: will try and report back :)

Comment: Good luck @weinde.  Sorry about all the down votes.  I really don't understand why everyone seems to be against you.

Comment: no worries mate... its like this on every site of StackExchange... every new member gets bashed down in instance... 
Btw... I got the hat yesterday after like half an hour of waiting... but thanks for the answer man :) but i did exactly what you posted in the screenshots and a few more things...

Comment: @weinde - glad to meet you - take care.

Comment: same here bro! :)

Answer (score 23):

Update all **required information** and **wait**

Comment: Where did you get this info?  This is a direct quote from the hat *create or update at least two items in your Stack Overflow Developer Story*

Answer (score 6):

Given all online and mobile games where you're spoiled by achievement notifications within milliseconds of you fulfilling the criteria, it would seem reasonable to expect the same here.

However, Stack Overflow's achievement systems actually rely on database scripts that run in a loop, which intermittently timeout at that.

So no, you won't get hats after executing the single click that made you fulfill the criteria, you'll have to wait. If the system didn't assign the proper badge or hat after a couple of hours, only then you're allowed to come and tell that on Meta.

[Q.E.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.):

> I got the hat yesterday after like half an hour of waiting

Comment: I edited a ton of stuff in my dev story last night, but this morning I still do not have the hat.  To be honest, this answer seems kind of snarky to me.  It's not really helpful.

Comment: @Jess I didn't intend it to sound like that. That being said, I don't really care whether you consider it helpful; it's the truth.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point?  That we help each other?  You imply that the OP is complaining.

Comment: I'm not implying anything, I'm even calling their expectations reasonable in my first sentence. I'm really not quite sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but you should either remove this answer or clean it up a bit.  Saying someone is **not allowed** to post on meta or calling them a complainer is uncalled for.

Comment: **You** are the one giving "complain" a negative connotation, not me. English is not my first language though, there may be a better word for it. I'm also not saying someone is not allowed to complain; I'm telling them to wait a bit before doing so. The OP even commented on your answer that the hat in question was awarded after half an hour.