# The NeverEnding Story hat not received

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2016

I have fulfilled criteria for obtaining ['The NeverEnding Story'](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/the-neverending-story) hat, i.e. update two items in your developer story and I have already done that 2 days ago but still haven't received the hat. What's the issue with this?

Comment: Does [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339823/the-neverending-story-hat) help you any further?

Comment: @Glorfindel No I have done all of that, even updated recommended readings and also updated on two separate days

Answer (score 7):

There was a bug with how the criteria of the hat were defined in code.

This has now been fixed and you should be getting your hat soon.

Answer (score 1):

As said by **Oded** that it was a **bug** with the criteria that seems to be fixed now. I finally got that hat today.